# How to handle the event fired continuously?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

I tried to hook the three events in same name like as below

```
this.textFontFace.TextChanged += Format_TextChanged;
this.textFontSize.TextChanged += Format_TextChanged;
this.textFontType.TextChanged += Format_TextChanged;
```

Now, i changed TextBox value for `textFontFace`, `Format_TextChanged` method fired three times. I need to fired only one time based on changes made TextBox. How can i handle this? 
please, help.

Comment: That shouldn't happen based on the code you show.  Are you somehow passing through that code three times and adding each event more than once?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you set those event handlers via both designer and code behind. If you clear TextChanged boxes of properties tab from design view you will get rid of the problem.